# Scala: How to return a tuple in a function? "type mismatch"

Tags: scala, gremlin-scala

I'm using the library `gremlin-scala` to interact with Janusgraph.

Using the DSL, a way to insert a new vertex is by doing the following:

```
val Id = Key[Long]("id")
val Name = Key[String]("name")
graph + ("label", Id -> 42, Name -> "Mike")
```

I want to make this part into a a function `("label", Id -> 42, Name -> "Mike")`

```
case class VertexModel(id: Long, name: String) {
  def toVertex: (Label, KeyValue[Long], KeyValue[String]) = {
    val Id = Key[Long]("id")
    val Name = Key[String]("name")
    ("item", Id -> id, Name -> name)
  }
}

val model = VertexModel(1, "Bill")
graph + model.toVertex
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Error:(26, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : T1
 required: gremlin.scala.Label
    (which expands to)  String
    graph + vertex
Error:(26, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : T2
 required: gremlin.scala.KeyValue[Long]
    graph + vertex
Error:(26, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : T3
 required: gremlin.scala.KeyValue[String]
    graph + vertex
```

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: From `gremlin-scala`'s source code it looks like the argument to `+` on a graph isn't a tuple but just a regular argument list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need extension method `toVertex`?

Doesn't this work just like

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph

object App {

  implicit val graph: ScalaGraph = TinkerGraph.open.asScala

  case class VertexModel(id: Long, name: String) 

  val model = VertexModel(1, "Bill")
  graph + model
}
```

?

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.4.0.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tinkerpop" % "tinkergraph-gremlin" % "3.4.0"
```

Comment: That's cool! Didn't know that was possible. 1 more question: How can I add the label to the class? Expanding on your solution: `case class VertexModel(label: Label, id: Long, name: String)`, I get `Name cannot be in protected namespace: label`

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. `case class VertexModel(label: Label, id: Long, name: String)`
`val model = VertexModel("item", 1, "Bill")`
`graph + model` compiles for me.

Comment: That's during runtime by the gremlin server

Comment: Another issue is that I cannot use different `Key` names. For example I want a key `type` but I can't do `case class VertexModel(type: String, id: Long, name: String)` because `type` is a keyword.

Comment: What if you try `label, type` in backticks?